# How to send api requests in real time in JS?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

With this XHR request it would only send request once, if this is done with setTimeout it can repeatedly send request but how to do that in real time? Like on some websites we can see real time bitcoin prices. I read about EventSource but can't understand how it's used.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status == 200){
        document.write(this.responseText)'
        }
     }
        xhr.open("GET","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json",true);
        xhr.send();
```

Comment: There are two ways to get real time data.
1) Using sockets
2) Pooling AJAX calls. SetInterval every 1sec or 2

Depending on the application its your call to integrate whats best.

Comment: by the way, you don't want to do `document.write` ... ever ... especially in an asynchronous callback

Comment: @Bravo why not ```document.write``` ? And what else

Comment: DOM manipulation ... document.write in asynch callback will write over the document if I remember correctly, therefore wiping the page - I could be wrong (doesn't happen often though)

Comment: what should be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

With XHR, you can simulate with a Pull by either setTimeout or setInterval, but if you want more instant response, you'll have to set up a WebSocket server.

Not every browser supports websocket, so you'll have to fall back to the Timeout/Interval pulling.

Similar to an XHR object, a WebSocket object defines onopen, onmessage and onerror callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data via EventSource you would need to have a server that implements SSE

> Server-sent Events (SSE) is a specification that allows servers to send events directly to clients that subscribe to those events, similar to WebSockets and related server to client push technologies.

An implementation of `EventSource` looks something like this (take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) link):

```js
var evtSource = new EventSource('sse.php');
var eventList = document.querySelector('ul');

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");

  newElement.textContent = "message: " + e.data;
  eventList.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

If the event generator script is hosted on a different origin, a new `EventSource` object should be created with both the URL and an options dictionary.

```js
const evtSource = new EventSource("//api.example.com/ssedemo.php", { withCredentials: true } );
```

---

In this case you have a REST API, not a SSE, so the best you can get with that to have real-time information is to use a `setTimeout` function to repeat the Ajax call every n period of time.

Comment: For EventSource do we need access to the server?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the event generator script is in a different origin you can create the EventSource object with the URL and an options dictionary. I'll edit my answer and add that.