# How to send api requests without xhr, fetch or even websockets?

Tags: javascript, api, real-time

how does this website (https://www.investing.com/equities/microsoft-corp) updates dom in realtime, how are they sending requests to the price api? I checked they are not using xhr requests and not even fetch, how exactly they are sending requests to the api and updating dom in realtime.

Here is how I am doing it. ([How to send api requests in real time in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908216/how-to-send-api-requests-in-real-time-in-js))

EDIT: Currently US stock market is closed so the price is not updating. Please check for some other country which is open while you read this question.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the network tab in your browser's developer tools. You can see that they use a WebSocket.

[image: network tab]

Comment: I can't find their websocket code in source code, can you check please?

Comment: No. It really isn't worth anyone's time to do that. If you want to use websockets in your own project there there are plenty of tutorials and documentation out there.

Comment: @Sam the code might be obfuscated or something. Look up socket.io if you want to learn how to make a websocket connection yourself.